# Facebook App to Redirect to an external website

Tags: facebook, redirect

I am trying to get an App to redirect to an external website. I have found a company who has done it (See [image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/nk86o)). If you type in their name "Safarinow" the first result comes up which is an App. When you click the app you get redirected to "http://www.safarinow.com".

Would anyone know how to achieve this?

p.s. I am not actually a developer but rather a Social media manager so I have a limited understanding of coding etc. I have just been asked to find out how to do this for the lazy dev team.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be done by using Javascript in your application iframe. That javascript can change the top-url like that:

```
window.top.location = 'http://www.my-website.com/';
```

You just have to run this code when your website is loaded. For example by using jQuery:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() { window.top.location = 'http://www.my-website.com/'; });
```

Comment: I use this approach, but the problem is that there is no longer a way to go "back" to the main Facebook page unless you hit back twice in rapid succession.  Personally, as a tech-savvy individual, this doesn't bother me, but our users are consistently put off by this.  Any recommendations?